# Checkbox and Css style color

Tags: javascript

I want to know how I can change the color of "box" in checkbox by clicking on that. I do not want to change the color of labels I just want to change the color of box by clicking of it.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="1" class="styled green"/> 1
 <input type="checkbox" name="2" class="styled red" checked/> 2
 <input type="checkbox" name="3" class="styled purple" /> 3
```

Comment: Refer below links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257629/change-color-by-checking-checkbox

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432286/html-checkbox-change-color

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can't do this. You need to play with css and some javascript and have to use custom checkbox.

One of the possible example is [here](http://www.jotform.org/html-elements/how-to-change-checkbox-size-css/)

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick (need bit testing and finetuning though, especially at checkbox's state) ;

```
// elementbyid shorthand
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

// this function handles background color
var markCheckbox = function(e) {
    // find id + class name
    var showId = e.target.id;
    var color = e.className
    // change color
    $(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
};

// this gets invoked when page got loaded
window.addEventistener('load', function() {
    var getElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // loop through all input elements
    for(var i = 0; i < getElements.length; i++) {
        // control if it's a checkbox + bind click event.
        if(getElements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            (getElements[i].id).addEventListener('click', markCheckbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2<sub>¢</sub> of mine:

http://roxon.in/scripts/checkbox_radio_custom.html

Basically with a couple of lines of JS - jQuery, you can replace the checkboxes with a`<span>` element. (Or with two like I did in my example link if you want to go fancy.)

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    var $c = $(this);
    $c.hide().after('<span/>');
    $c.next('span').click(function(){
        $c[0].checked^=1;
    });
});
```

than all you need is to **be creative** using CSS and CSS3 animations.
Here's how to target your `SPAN` that jQuery appended **after** the hidden `INPUT`:

```
/* target the hidden checkbox's next SPAN element: */
input[type=checkbox] + span{

}
/* Custom checkbox HOVER: */
input[type=checkbox] + span:hover{

}
/* Custom checkbox CHECKED STATE */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + span{

}
```

Have fun.